# Synchronizing two threads with locking

Tags: java, concurrency

I have to threads, that need to be synchronized. I have tried to use a ReadWriteLock but found that in some cases a deadlock happens.

I have a class that is creating a connection to a serial port and registering an event listener to receive data:

```
public class AppSerialPort implements SerialPortEventListener, Closeable {
  private final SerialPort serialPort;

  private final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

  private final ReadWriteLock graphLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
  private final Lock graphWriteLock = graphLock.writeLock();
  private final Lock graphReadLock = graphLock.readLock();

  private PipedOutputStream graphPacketOutputStream;
  private PipedInputStream graphPacketInputStream;
  private boolean graphInputStreamOpen;
  private boolean connectionClosed;

  public AppSerialPort(String portIdentifier) throws NoSuchPortException, PortInUseException, TooManyListenersException, UnsupportedCommOperationException, IOException {
    CommPortIdentifier portId = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(portIdentifier);
    this.serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open("MyApp", 0);

    this.initListener();
  }

  public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
    try {
      if (event.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE && !connectionClosed) {
        int available = serialPort.getInputStream().available();
        if (available > 0) {
          byte[] buffer = new byte[available];
          serialPort.getInputStream().read(buffer);
          handleEventData(buffer);
        }
      }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      /*ignore*/
    }
  }

  private synchronized void handleEventData(final byte[] buffer) { 
    Callable<Void> eventHandlerTask = () -> {
      if (graphInputStreamOpen) {
        graphReadLock.lock();

        try {
          graphPacketOutputStream.write(buffer);
        } finally { 
          graphReadLock.unlock(); 
        }
      }

      return null;
    };

    Future<Void> future = executor.submit(eventHandlerTask);

    try {
      future.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
      serialPort.removeEventListener();
    }
  }

  private void initListener() throws TooManyListenersException {
    serialPort.addEventListener(this);
    serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
  }

  public InputStream openGraphInputStream() throws IOException {
    graphPacketOutputStream = new PipedOutputStream();
    graphPacketInputStream = new PipedInputStream(15000);

    graphPacketInputStream.connect(graphPacketOutputStream);
    graphInputStreamOpen = true;

    return graphPacketInputStream;
  }

  public void closeGraphInputStream() throws IOException {
    graphWriteLock.lock();

    try {
      graphInputStreamOpen = false;
      graphPacketInputStream.close();
      graphPacketOutputStream.close();
    } finally { 
      graphWriteLock.unlock(); 
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void close() throws IOException {
    connectionClosed = true;
    serialPort.removeEventListener();
    serialPort.close();
  }
}
```

The deadlock happens when a serial event is processed and the `graphReadLock` is waiting to lock, but at the same time close has been called and the `graphWriteLock` is also waiting to lock.

I am using `PipedInputStream` and `PipedOutputStream` and when `closeGraphInputStream()` is called the inputstream might already be closed which leads to an IOException during handling of the serial event.

How can I synchronize the state of the inputstream correctly?

Comment: How are your locks defined? Please provide a [mre], because I guess using a `ReadWriteLock` is the wrong tool for the job, because as written you can have multiple readers concurrently (which is what a `ReadWriteLock` allows), but you shouldn't, especially not as your readers also *write* under a read lock.

Comment: I'd suggest replacing those locks with a single ReentrantLock, but I find your code very confusing. For example: why doesn't `serialEvent` take out a lock? Why does `handleEventData` check `graphInputStreamOpen`, while it actually uses `graphPacketOutputStream`. In addition, your use of `InputStream.available()` is suspicious, as you might not read a full message that way.

Comment: I have tried to reduce the code to the lock problem, that is why some information is missing here. `serialEvent` does not take out a lock, because I need to analyze the data before and depending on the contents some more logic is used in the `handleEventData` method. 
The check for `graphInputStreamOpen` was my first try of synchronization. I think this is obsolete as far as the locking is working correctly.

Comment: To echo @MarkRotteveel, please provide a minimal reproducible example and it's not clear what you're trying to achieve with the read-write locks. Multiple concurrent readers are permitted and writing is exclusive (including against reading). But 'consuming' reading (reading from a stream buffer) is in data terms a write to the stream (updating that the data is consumed). Hope that gets you somewhere!